# Issue with provider when navigating between screens

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-provider

I'm trying to learn more about provider but I'm facing an issue with an app I'm developing, specifically when I navigate to a screen. When I press on the button to take me to the history_screen is when I get an error from Provider, all the providers are declared at the top of the tree so not really sure why there's still an error.
Hopefully someone can help me!
See my code below and the error I get:

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
      MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<Meds>>.value(
            value: MedicinesNotifier().medicinesStream(),
            initialData: MedicinesNotifier().meds,
            updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true),
        //ChangeNotifierProvider<MedicinesNotifier>(create: (_) => MedicinesNotifier()),
        ProxyProvider<List<Meds>,MedicinesNotifier>(
          update:
              (BuildContext context, List<Meds> meds1, MedicinesNotifier? medNoti) => MedicinesNotifier.med(meds1)
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchHistoryData>(create: (_) => SearchHistoryData()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        /*theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),*/
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home_page.dart**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Meds> medFiltered = [];
  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();
  String searchText = "";
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSearching = searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: searchController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: new BorderSide(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    Provider.of<MedicinesNotifier>(context, listen: false)
                        .changeSearchString(value);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: 
                    ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: isSearching == true
                      ? context
                          .watch<MedicinesNotifier>()
                          .meds 
                          .length 
                      : context
                          .watch<List<Meds>>()
                          .length, 
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Meds med = isSearching == true
                        ? context
                                .watch<MedicinesNotifier>()
                                .meds 
                            [index] 
                        : context
                            .watch<List<Meds>>()[index]; //medsStreamed[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        context.read<MedicinesNotifier>().addHistory(med);
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                                      med: context.watch<MedicinesNotifier>().findMedicine(med),
                                    )));
                      },
                      title: Text(med.name),
                      subtitle: Text(med.description.substring(0, 10)),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**BottomBar widget**

```
class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              color: Colors.white,
              iconSize: 40.0,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              icon: Icon(Icons.history_edu),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HistoryScreen()));
              },**//Causing the issue**
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**history_screen.dart**

```
class HistoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HistoryScreenState createState() => _HistoryScreenState();
}

class _HistoryScreenState extends State<HistoryScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //List<Meds> temp1 = context.watch<MedicinesNotifier>().history;
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 0.0, 15.0, 30.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              "Filter",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.white54,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white30,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    child: Consumer<SearchHistoryData?>(**//Using Consumer here**
                        builder: (context, searchHistoryData, child) {
                      //assert(child != null);
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: searchHistoryData!.sizeOfHistory(),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            //final  historyData =
                            return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(...
```

**Exception caught**

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<SearchHistoryData?>(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<SearchHistoryData?> above this Consumer<SearchHistoryData?> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer<SearchHistoryData?> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<SearchHistoryData?>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you tried removing `?` in `Consumer<SearchHistoryData?>`?

Comment: @rickimaru you're right that was the issue, thanks! what a silly mistake from my side, I'm still also learning stuff on null safety , why was it showing error because of this "?"? Is that saying that it could be null as well if not mistaken correct?

Comment: It's trying to find a nullable `SearchHistoryData`, but you only provided a NON-NULLABLE `SearchHistoryData`. That's why it can't find the correct provider.